# Как создать файл с помощью приложения на Android через С++?

Tags: java, c++, файлы, android-ndk

Есть приложение на Android написанное на Java с использованием библиотек написанных на С++ с помощью Android NDK. Нужно, чтобы в одном из методов библиотеки С++ **ПРИ РАБОТЕ ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ** создавался файл (в какой-то определенный каталог). Как это можно сделать? Или уже есть готовые методы?

Сразу извиняюсь, если вопрос поставлен не совсем "корректно".

Answer (score 1):

Так чтоли?

```
FILE * ptrFile = fopen("file.txt", "w");

  if (ptrFile != NULL)
  {
    fputs("Пример использования функции fopen ", ptrFile); // записать строку в файл
    fclose (ptrFile);
  }
```

Comment: нужно, чтобы, например, при использовании какой-нибудь функции в приложении записывалась какая-либо информация (логи допустим) в файл. Т.е. я на смартфоне после закрытия приложения открываю соответствующий каталог, а там лежит созданный файлик. Ваш вариант создает файл и записывает информацию, но будет ли этот файл создан где-либо на Андроиде?

Comment: @VadoM будет. Вопрос только в каком каталоге.

Comment: @pavel, не знаете ли как именно указать нужный каталог? Например, чтобы файл создавался на карте памяти.

Comment: @VadoM я бы рекомендовал передавать в функцию путь к файлу. Можно конечно использовать какой-нибудь `sdcard/file.txt`  но надёжнее у андроида спросить.

Comment: @sitev_ru нужно, чтобы, например, при использовании какой-нибудь функции в приложении записывалась какая-либо информация (логи допустим) в файл. Т.е. я на смартфоне после закрытия приложения открываю соответствующий каталог, а там лежит созданный файлик. Ваш вариант создает файл и записывает информацию, но будет ли этот файл создан где-либо на Андроиде? Я продублировал комент, так как вопрос остается открытым, и я подумал, что вы можете помочь, но предыдущий мой ответ не заметили)